# Creating display on-hover main menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm fairly new to the WordPress, and I needed to create a menu. I did it by adding these lines into *functions.php*,

```
<?php
function add_mainmenu_header()
{
register_nav_menu('header-mainmenu',__( 'Header Main Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_mainmenu_header' );
?>
```

I get the menu into header by this,

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'Main_Header' => 'add_mainmenu_header',
'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 
'container' => false ) ); 
?>
```

I've tried to add few sub menus. which should display in hover.

but when I hover on menu item (I has a few `li` elements as menu items), it shows the sub menu items,

My problem is, right after I try moving into the expanded sub menu, it disappears immediately. how can I go from hovered div to expanded menu items using css?

Comment: There might be a margin which acts as a void space therefore losing the hover effect on your element. But I'm not sure I understand correctly your problem, do you have any code to share ?

Comment: We need to see the output html + css, or, even better, a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) code

Comment: You could use css transitions to let the submenu stay for a while. Look it up here: [MDN CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: @D.Schaller Thanks. I will check it

Comment: @ThomasMilan what section do you need?

Comment: @MoshFeu could you please let me know which section you needs?

Comment: The menu part. So we can see why the sub menu is closing too soon.